# Websocket session.Path

Tags: websocket

I've been playing around with the SuperWebSocket code, pretty cool stuff, but I'm not sure why we really need to set the path at the end of the url as in:

ws = new WebSocket('ws://<%= Request.Url.Host %>:<%= WebSocketPort %>/sample');

I left the 'sample' at the end out from the url and it still works. Why do we need it at all? I didn't see anywhere in the code where it was used except for some logging.

Can someone shed some light on the 'session.Path' thing?

Thanks much,

Answer (score 1):

The path part of the URL is so that you could have different WebSocket server applications running on the same port. In other words, WebSocket connections default to 80 and 443 in order to use existing infrastructure and network configuration. However, you still might want to serve multiple WebSocket applications so that is what the path is for. If you only have a single application running on that port, then you can ignore the path.